# how to stay on same tab when came back to the children of each tab in Django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, content-management-system, wagtail

In my Django page, I have two tabs.Tab1 and Tab2 right. And Each Tab has a number of children. If I navigate to Tab1's children, the Same as if I navigate to Tab2's children. If I came back to the parent(Tab1 or Tab2) it will always go to Tab1.

If I navigate through Tab1 than it will come back to Tab1 and if I navigate through Tab2 than it will come back to Tab2. How to do this in Django?

Comment: Post existing code and what you have tried to do what you want to do.